# Batch writes log only when success in block execution

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In a code like this

```
(
    @echo before
    <my .net build command line>
    @echo after %ERRORLEVEL%
) >> mylog.txt
```

If my .net build command builds successfully, I get everything written into mylog.txt. But if solution build fails, nothing written. And I know that `errorlevel` is 1 (remove `>> mylog.txt` to test). I want even failed output to write to log. How to deal with this?

Comment: Here is a really useful webpage on [redirection](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

Comment: Forgot to mention that the `%errorlevel%` will not output correctly because you are inside a parenthesized code block. You need to use delayed expansion for the variable to output correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fixed version of the script.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

(
@echo before
@rem [my .net build command line]
@ECHO AFTER !ERRORLEVEL!
) >> mylog.txt 2>&1
```

Squashman mentioned the delayed expansion problem. So I don't explain here.

The `2>&1` redirects STDERR to STDOUT, and then redirect the combined STDOUT to `mylog.txt`.

Comment: You did not answer the main question as to why the error condition is not being output to the log file. File stream 2 which is standard error needs to be redirected to output to the log file.

Comment: Hmm. I must have missed that.

Comment: `>> mylog.txt 2>&1` will redirect standard output and standard error to the log file.

Comment: I don't understand OP's requirement. Does he/she want STDERR when there's error, and STDOUT when it's fine?

Comment: My understanding is they want standard error and standard output written to the log file which is why I linked to an article on redirection in my initial comment.

Comment: According to your comment, my current version(`>> mylog.txt 2>&1`) is correct.